# User friendly way to toggle between text variants in the editor

Tags: block-editor

Gutenberg / block editor:

The website contains a paragraph that is often (manually) changed between two (or three) texts (that hardly ever chance), let's say:

- Sorry, currently no places available
- Sorry, currently no places available, but please contact us to be put on the waiting list
- Please contact us for available places

Is there a recommended way so that the user can *easily* und intuitively select one of these texts, and still edit the texts? (I am thinking of three text boxes in the editor, one of which can be selected with a radio button, each on editable.)

How would I implement this?

Comment: it sounds like you want the user to be able to select predefined text, a radio control doesn't make sense for this as soon as you add the requirement that they can edit the text still. Do block patterns not provide this? This also sounds like it's trying to solve a problem you've not mentioned, e.g. that there's no conditional block for unmentioned functionality, would it not be useful to ask about that? I've edited out the request for a recommendation as those are offtopic here and would get your question closed.